# Access data of a domain user from admin account of that domain

Tags: google-apps-script

I am admin of a domain & i want to access & download the
data(docs,contacts,sites,calenders,emails) of my domain user...Is it possible and how ? 
please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer. 
Yes,we can access docs, calenders,sites and emails of a domain user from admin account via google script but we cannot access contacts of a domain user from admin account

Comment: your question was "is it possible and how ?"... how does this (own) response answer your question ? I find it rather vague and ambiguous.

Comment: I have just given answer of my "Is it possible" question..I thought if  any one need help for this type of query then he will find it useful..

Comment: The interesting part would have been how.  and a code to do it. This is just a 'Yes we can'  not anybody gets successful with such a simple statement :-)

Comment: the how part was my query and i got my solution. If anybody will have problem in how part in future then i will reply for sure for that also...:-)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible for domain admins to access user data using Google Apps Script.

Comment: But i am able to fetch user's sites, calenders and docs and share  that data to user's another account.....but i am unable to download that data